# Сохранение цвета фона кнопки после ее уничтожения

Tags: android

Нажатие одной кнопки меняет цвет другой кнопки. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сохранить новый цвет фона кнопки после уничтожения активности.

```
private Button oneButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    oneButton=findViewById(R.id.oneButton);
}

public void twoButton(View view) {
    oneButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
}
```

}

Comment: Вы пишите, что нажатие одной кнопки меняет цвет другой кнопки.Но в коде этого не видно.Разъясните. Нужен onClickListener, чтобы отследить нажатие. Сохранить цвет можно несколькими методами. Можно передать в другую активность. Можно сохранить в Preferences. Можно в файл или бд на диске. Но у вас в R.color.black уже известен этот цвет.  Поэтому непонятно зачем сохранять?

Comment: Извиняюсь за неверный код. Исправил. Сохранять нужно для того, чтобы после уничтожения активности, цвет кнопки сохранялся при новом запуске.

Comment: @Ikibana, сохраните цвет в к-л виде (числом, сторокой) в `SharedPreferences` и при старте активити назначайте кнопке цвет из `SharedPreferences` взятый

Comment: А как можно сделать тоже самое, только чтобы twoButton не была константой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final String BUTTON_COLOR_PREF = "Button Color";
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;



    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences(BUTTON_COLOR_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final Button oneButton = findViewById(R.id.oneButton);
    Button twoButton = findViewById(R.id.twoButton);
    oneButton.setBackgroundColor(mPreferences.getInt(BUTTON_COLOR_PREF, getResources().getColor(R.color.red)));
    //цвет, который будет устанавливаться, пока вы не нажали кнопку первый раз. В данном случае красный. После того как нажмете кнопку он сохранится и будет черный

    twoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int colorId = getResources().getColor(R.color.black);
            oneButton.setBackgroundColor(colorId);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
            editor.putInt(BUTTON_COLOR_PREF, colorId);
            editor.apply();

        }
    });
```